# Using an Angular component as form control

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Consider the following form

```
   <div [formGroup]="form">

        <div [ngSwitch]="control.controlType">

            <div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
                <label [attr.for]="control.key">{{control.label}}</label>
                <input [formControlName]="control.key" [id]="control.key" type="checkbox"
                    (change)="evaluate(control.key)">
            </div>

            <app-multiple-checkbox [formControlName]="control.key"  *ngSwitchCase="'multipleCheckbox'"
                [options]="control.options" (change)="evaluate(control.key)">
            </app-multiple-checkbox>
        </div>

    </div>
```

My Form is built dynamically. It is made of checkboxesa and a custom component `multiple-checkbox`. Everything works fine with simple checkboxes but with the custom component I get the following  error:

> Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'content-type'

'content-type' is the value of `control.key` passed to the formControlName attribute of my custom compoent.

- MultipleCheckboxComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-multiple-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './multiple-checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multiple-checkbox.component.scss']
})
export class MultipleCheckboxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() public options: { key, value }[];
  @Output() haschanged = new EventEmitter();


  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.options);
  }

  evaluate(key): void {
    this.haschanged.emit(key, this.options);
  }
}
```

- MultipleCheckboxComponent.html

  ```
  <div *ngFor="let option of options">
       <label [attr.for]="option.key">{{option.value}}</label>
        <input [id]="option.key" type="checkbox" (change)="evaluate(control.key)">
   </div>
  ```

I understand that I'm missing something here to make it a form component but I can't figure out what.
Particularly, the value of this custom form control should be the id's of the selected checkboxes. How can I specify that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide [NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR](https://angular.io/api/forms/NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) DI token for your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => HelloComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

And implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface. Then Angular forms API will treat your component as a functional form control.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-unfcgw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) is the sample code for `HelloComopnent` which is a custom form control.

Comment: Exactely why I needed ! It works perfect :)  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but
I believe you should define and initialize property

control:{controlType:whateverType, ...}

for your component

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not sure I understand what you mean.